# PHP MySQL Form Pagination

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

I am doing a pagination in PHP from records in Database MySQL.
I have in total 7 records to display, I have set numbers per page (resultsPerPage) as 2, so I will be displaying 4 pages.
I am displaying results from two queries:

1. First is table tblPaciente which shows information from my client.
2. Second is table tblEvolucion which shows information which I required to apply the pagination. (7 records to display)

I am displaying a query from table tblEvolucion and displaying order by clmSerie column descending.

- Page 1 I want to display records with Description: "Record 7" and "Record 6"
- Page 2 I want to display records with Description: "Record 5" and "Record 4"
- Page 3 I want to display records with Description: "Record 3" and "Record 2"
- Page 4 I want to display record with Description: "Record 1"

My problem is when I press "Previous Page", "Next Page" or any of the displaying pages (1,2,3,4), the form is being reset and is showing me nothing but the FORM (id=frmPacienteBuscar) empty, with no results.  I required to display it to me next page and remains table results (id=table1) from the first query and also remain the form (id=frmPacienteBuscar).

If I search again in the form after it has been reset it will access to the page that I went before.
For example:
- First I load the page.
- Then I press page number 3
- Then everything is blank and I have to retype inputs with ids (id="searchByRut" and id="dv")
- Then I will be accessing immediately from page number 3

I have tried to pass in the HREF of my "Next Page" the variable $searchByRut, with is required for me to search in table tblPaciente and tblEvolucion but it is saying to me that is undefined index after I press a link to access any page.  Here:

```
$outputTblEvolucion .= " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?currentPage=$prevpage'> Previous Page </a> ";
```

I am trying to capture it as follows at the beginning of my PHP code:

```
$searchByRut  = $_POST["searchByRut"];
```

I assume that I required to pass as POST in the HREF of every link to pages the RUT but I am not able to catch it and also not sure if that is the problem.
Please let me know any clarification, thanks in advance,

testPaginization3.php

```
<?php
    include_once('funcionesComunes.php');
    require_once('mysqli_connect.php');
    $outputTblEvolucion = '';
    $outputTblPaciente = $outputData = '';
    $searchByRut_error = '';
    $searchByRut = '';
    $dv_input = '';
    $iCompleteFirstQuery = $iHaveToDoSecondQuery = 0;
    $countDataFromTblPaciente = 0;
    $searchByRut  = $_POST["searchByRut"];
    if(isset($_POST['searchByRut']))
    {
        //there are just validation if my id entered to search is valid, please ignore this part:
        $error = '';
        $dv                   = $_POST["dv"];
        $dv_input             = $_POST["dv"];
        $searchByRut  = $_POST["searchByRut"];
        echo "<br>". "searchByRut={" . $searchByRut ."}";
        if ($dv == "k") 
            $dv = "K";
        $searchByRut_error = rutValidar($searchByRut, $dv, $error);
        
        //here I am checking if any error occurred in the previous validation
        if ($searchByRut_error == '')
        {
            $rut = $_POST['searchByRut'];
            $queryDatosPaciente = mysqli_query($dbc,
                                       "SELECT CONCAT(pa.clmNombres, ' ', pa.clmApellidos) as clmNombres
                                              ,pa.clmEmail
                                       FROM    tblPaciente    pa
                                         WHERE  pa.clmRut    = '$rut'
                                          "
                                ) or die('Error while searching!: {' . mysqli_error($dbc) . '}');
            $countDataFromTblPaciente = mysqli_num_rows($queryDatosPaciente);
            $iCompleteFirstQuery = 1;
            
        }
    }
    
    //this variable iCompleteFirstQuery will tell me that I have to execute second query in detail table tblEvolucion, because I found already the main record in customer table tblPaciente
    if ($iCompleteFirstQuery == 1)
    {
        if($countDataFromTblPaciente == 0)
        {
            $outputTblPaciente = 'It did not find client!';
            $iHaveToDoSecondQuery = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            //Here I just build the Table with result from query of customer tblPaciente
            $iHaveToDoSecondQuery = 1;
            $outputTblPaciente .= "<table id='table1' border='1' align='left' cellspacing='5' cellpadding='8'>";
            $outputTblPaciente .= "<tr><td align='left'><b>Name     </b></td>
                                         <td align='left'><b>Email  </b></td>
                                     </tr>";
            
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($queryDatosPaciente))
            {
                $nombres    = utf8_encode($row['clmNombres']);
                $email      = $row['clmEmail'];
                
                $outputTblPaciente .= "<td align='left'> $nombres      </td>
                                         <td align='left'> $email        </td>";
                $outputTblPaciente .= "</tr></table><br><br><br><br><br>";
            }
        }
    }
    
    //In this IF condition is the part that I required to make as pagination, for the result of table tblEvolucion
    if ($iHaveToDoSecondQuery == 1)
    {
        $sqlCount = "SELECT  COUNT(*)
                    FROM     tblEvolucion    ev
                    WHERE    ev.clmRut = '$rut'";
        $resultadoQueryCount = mysqli_query($dbc,$sqlCount) or die('Error to select!: {' . mysqli_error($dbc) . '}');
            
        $r = mysqli_fetch_row($resultadoQueryCount);
        $countRecordsFound = $r[0];
        echo "<br>". "countRecordsFound={" . $countRecordsFound ."}";
        echo "<br><br>";
        
        $resultsPerPage = 2;
        $totalPages = ceil($countRecordsFound / $resultsPerPage);
        
        // get the current page or set a default
        if (isset($_GET['currentPage']) && is_numeric($_GET['currentPage']))
        {
            // cast var as int
            $currentPage = (int) $_GET['currentPage'];
        }
        else
        {
            // default page num
            $currentPage = 1;
        }
        
        // if current page is greater than total pages...
        if ($currentPage > $totalPages)
        {
            // set current page to last page
            $currentPage = $totalPages;
        }
        // if current page is less than first page...
        if ($currentPage < 1)
        {
            // set current page to first page
            $currentPage = 1;
        }
        
        // the offset of the list, based on current page 
        $offset = ($currentPage - 1) * $resultsPerPage;
        
        // get the info from the db 
        $sqlDespliegaDatos ="SELECT ev.clmDescripcion
                             FROM     tblEvolucion    ev
                             WHERE    ev.clmRut    = '$rut'
                             ORDER by ev.clmSerie DESC
                             LIMIT  $offset
                                   ,$resultsPerPage";
        $resultadoQueryDespliegaDatos = mysqli_query($dbc,$sqlDespliegaDatos) or die('Error to select!: {' . mysqli_error($dbc) . '}');
        
        $iHaveToDoSecondQuery = 1;
        if($countRecordsFound == 0)
        {
            $outputData = 'No results from Table tblEvolucion!';
        }
        else
        {
            //From there I build the table with my records from tblEvolucion wish I required to be with pagination
            $outputData = '';
            $outputData .= '<table border=1 align="left" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="8">
                                        <tr><td align="left"><b>Description                  </b></td>
                                    </tr>';
                                    
            while ($list = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultadoQueryDespliegaDatos))
            {
                $descripcion               = utf8_encode($list['clmDescripcion']);
                
                $outputData .= '<tr>';
                $outputData .= "<td align='left'><textarea id='descripcion' name='descripcion' tabindex='4' cols='50' rows='6' maxlength='1000'
                                                           value = '".$descripcion."' 
                                                           readonly>".($descripcion)."</textarea>
                                </td>";
                $outputData .= '</tr>';
                
            }
            $outputData .= '</table>';
            
            $outputTblEvolucion = '';
            /******  build the pagination links ******/
            // range of num links to show
            $range = 3;
            
            // if not on page 1, don't show back links
            if ($currentPage > 1)
            {
                // show << link to go back to page 1
                $outputTblEvolucion .= " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?currentPage=1'> << </a> ";
                // get previous page num
                $prevpage = $currentPage - 1;
                // show < link to go back to 1 page
                $outputTblEvolucion .= " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?currentPage=$prevpage'> Previous Page </a> ";
            }
            
            // loop to show links to range of pages around current page
            for ($x = ($currentPage - $range); $x < (($currentPage + $range) + 1); $x++)
            {
                // if it's a valid page number...
                if (($x > 0) && ($x <= $totalPages))
                {
                    // if we're on current page...
                    if ($x == $currentPage)
                    {
                        // 'highlight' it but don't make a link
                        $outputTblEvolucion .= " [<b>$x</b>] ";
                    // if not current page...
                    } else
                    {
                        // make it a link
                        $outputTblEvolucion .= " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?currentPage=$x'>$x</a> ";
                    }
                }
            }
                            
            // if not on last page, show forward and last page links        
            if ($currentPage != $totalPages)
            {
                // get next page
                $nextpage = $currentPage + 1;
                // echo forward link for next page
                //Here is which I think I am doing something wrong and I though to pass also my variable searchByRut but I am not able to received after pressing click on "Next Page"
                $outputTblEvolucion .= " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?currentPage=$nextpage"
                                                                          ."&searchByRut=$searchByRut
                                                                            '>Next Page</a> ";
                // echo forward link for lastpage
                $outputTblEvolucion .= " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?currentPage=$totalPages'>>></a> ";
            } // end if
        }
    }
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Pagination with Form</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Pagination with Form</h1>
        <form id="frmPacienteBuscar" action="" method="post">
            <fieldset>
                <span class="error"><?= $searchByRut_error ?></span><br>
                RUT: <input name="searchByRut" id="searchByRut" type="text" placeholder="Search by RUT.." tabindex="2" size="15" maxlength="8"
                            value="<?= $searchByRut ?>" > - 
                     <input name="dv" id="dv" type="text" value="<?= $dv_input ?>" size="1" tabindex="2" maxlength="1"
                            value="<?= $dv_input ?>" >  Sample: 12345678-1<br>
                <button name="buscar" type="submit" id="contact-submit" data-submit="...Sending">Search</button><br>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
        <?php
            /*Here I will be printing the result of:
                - the main table from tblPaciente
                - the table which I required to do pagination tblEvolucion
                - the links to navigate to the next and previous pages
            */
            echo $outputTblPaciente;
            echo "<br>";
            echo $outputData;
            echo "<br>";
            echo $outputTblEvolucion;
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

[image: Pagination Screenshot]
[image: After Pressing any page, the form is empty again]

Comment: if your using pagination, and your doing searches, you should probably use `$_GET` instead of post.  And this `$searchByRut  = $_POST["searchByRut"] ?? '';` if your using PHP7, or `$searchByRut  = isset($_POST["searchByRut"]) ? $_POST["searchByRut"] : '';` if your < 7  You should also read up on Prepareds statement and Sql Injection attacks.

Comment: [what is Sql Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601300/what-is-sql-injection)

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment @ArtisticPhoenix I am trying to get it work with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comment by @ArtisticPhoenix I will post solution with modified code:

Exactly I modify method from POST to GET and also I assined this way at the beginning of the code:

```
$searchByRut = isset($_POST["searchByRut"]) ? $_POST["searchByRut"] : '';
```

New code:

```
<?php
    include_once('funcionesComunes.php');
    require_once('mysqli_connect.php');
    $outputTblEvolucion = '';
    $outputTblPaciente = $outputData = '';
    $searchByRut_error = '';
    $searchByRut = '';
    $dv_input = '';
    $iCompleteFirstQuery = $iHaveToDoSecondQuery = 0;
    $countDataFromTblPaciente = 0;
    //$searchByRut = $_GET["searchByRut"];
    $searchByRut = isset($_GET["searchByRut"]) ? $_GET["searchByRut"] : '';
    $dv = isset($_GET["dv"]) ? $_GET["dv"] : '';
    echo "<br>". "0searchByRut={" . $searchByRut ."}";
    echo "<br>". "0dv={" . $dv ."}";
    if(isset($_GET['searchByRut']))
    {
        //there are just validation if my id entered to search is valid, please ignore this part:
        $error = '';
        $dv                   = $_GET["dv"];
        $dv_input             = $_GET["dv"];
        $searchByRut  = $_GET["searchByRut"];
        echo "<br>". "searchByRut={" . $searchByRut ."}";
        if ($dv == "k") 
            $dv = "K";
        $searchByRut_error = rutValidar($searchByRut, $dv, $error);

        //here I am checking if any error ocurred in the previous validation
        if ($searchByRut_error == '')
        {
            $rut = $_GET['searchByRut'];
            $queryDatosPaciente = mysqli_query($dbc,
                                       "SELECT CONCAT(pa.clmNombres, ' ', pa.clmApellidos) as clmNombres
                                              ,pa.clmEmail
                                       FROM    tblPaciente    pa
                                         WHERE  pa.clmRut    = '$rut'
                                          "
                                ) or die('Error while searching!: {' . mysqli_error($dbc) . '}');
            $countDataFromTblPaciente = mysqli_num_rows($queryDatosPaciente);
            $iCompleteFirstQuery = 1;

        }
    }

    //this variable iCompleteFirstQuery will tell me that I have to execute second query in detail table tblEvolucion, because I found already the main record in customer table tblPaciente
    if ($iCompleteFirstQuery == 1)
    {
        if($countDataFromTblPaciente == 0)
        {
            $outputTblPaciente = 'It did not find client!';
            $iHaveToDoSecondQuery = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            //Here I just build the Table with result from query of customer tblPaciente
            $iHaveToDoSecondQuery = 1;
            $outputTblPaciente .= "<table id='table1' border='1' align='left' cellspacing='5' cellpadding='8'>";
            $outputTblPaciente .= "<tr><td align='left'><b>Name     </b></td>
                                         <td align='left'><b>Email  </b></td>
                                     </tr>";

            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($queryDatosPaciente))
            {
                $nombres    = utf8_encode($row['clmNombres']);
                $email      = $row['clmEmail'];

                $outputTblPaciente .= "<td align='left'> $nombres      </td>
                                         <td align='left'> $email        </td>";
                $outputTblPaciente .= "</tr></table><br><br><br><br><br>";
            }
        }
    }

    //In this IF condition is the part that I required to make as pagination, for the result of table tblEvolucion
    if ($iHaveToDoSecondQuery == 1)
    {
        $sqlCount = "SELECT  COUNT(*)
                    FROM     tblEvolucion    ev
                    WHERE    ev.clmRut = '$rut'";
        $resultadoQueryCount = mysqli_query($dbc,$sqlCount) or die('Error to select!: {' . mysqli_error($dbc) . '}');

        $r = mysqli_fetch_row($resultadoQueryCount);
        $countRecordsFound = $r[0];
        echo "<br>". "countRecordsFound={" . $countRecordsFound ."}";
        echo "<br><br>";

        $resultsPerPage = 2;
        $totalPages = ceil($countRecordsFound / $resultsPerPage);

        // get the current page or set a default
        if (isset($_GET['currentPage']) && is_numeric($_GET['currentPage']))
        {
            // cast var as int
            $currentPage = (int) $_GET['currentPage'];
        }
        else
        {
            // default page num
            $currentPage = 1;
        }

        // if current page is greater than total pages...
        if ($currentPage > $totalPages)
        {
            // set current page to last page
            $currentPage = $totalPages;
        }
        // if current page is less than first page...
        if ($currentPage < 1)
        {
            // set current page to first page
            $currentPage = 1;
        }

        // the offset of the list, based on current page 
        $offset = ($currentPage - 1) * $resultsPerPage;

        // get the info from the db 
        $sqlDespliegaDatos ="SELECT ev.clmDescripcion
                             FROM     tblEvolucion    ev
                             WHERE    ev.clmRut    = '$rut'
                             ORDER by ev.clmSerie DESC
                             LIMIT  $offset
                                   ,$resultsPerPage";
        $resultadoQueryDespliegaDatos = mysqli_query($dbc,$sqlDespliegaDatos) or die('Error to select!: {' . mysqli_error($dbc) . '}');

        $iHaveToDoSecondQuery = 1;
        if($countRecordsFound == 0)
        {
            $outputData = 'No reults from Table tblEvolucion!';
        }
        else
        {
            //From there I build the table with my records from tblEvolucion wish I required to be with pagination
            $outputData = '';
            $outputData .= '<table border=1 align="left" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="8">
                                        <tr><td align="left"><b>Description                  </b></td>
                                    </tr>';

            while ($list = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultadoQueryDespliegaDatos))
            {
                $descripcion               = utf8_encode($list['clmDescripcion']);

                $outputData .= '<tr>';
                $outputData .= "<td align='left'><textarea id='descripcion' name='descripcion' tabindex='4' cols='50' rows='6' maxlength='1000'
                                                           value = '".$descripcion."' 
                                                           readonly>".($descripcion)."</textarea>
                                </td>";
                $outputData .= '</tr>';

            }
            $outputData .= '</table>';

            $outputTblEvolucion = '';
            /******  build the pagination links ******/
            // range of num links to show
            $range = 3;

            // if not on page 1, don't show back links
            if ($currentPage > 1)
            {
                // show << link to go back to page 1
                //$outputTblEvolucion .= " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?currentPage=1'> << </a> ";
                $outputTblEvolucion .= " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?currentPage=1"
                                                                          ."&searchByRut=$searchByRut"
                                                                          ."&dv=$dv
                                                                            '>First Page</a> ";
                // get previous page num
                $prevpage = $currentPage - 1;
                // show < link to go back to 1 page
                //$outputTblEvolucion .= " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?currentPage=$prevpage'> Previous Page+ </a> ";
                $outputTblEvolucion .= " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?currentPage=$prevpage"
                                                                          ."&searchByRut=$searchByRut"
                                                                          ."&dv=$dv
                                                                            '>Previous Page+ </a> ";

            }

            // loop to show links to range of pages around current page
            for ($x = ($currentPage - $range); $x < (($currentPage + $range) + 1); $x++)
            {
                // if it's a valid page number...
                if (($x > 0) && ($x <= $totalPages))
                {
                    // if we're on current page...
                    if ($x == $currentPage)
                    {
                        // 'highlight' it but don't make a link
                        $outputTblEvolucion .= " [<b>$x</b>] ";

                    // if not current page...
                    } else
                    {
                        // make it a link
                        //$outputTblEvolucion .= " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?currentPage=$x'>$x</a> ";
                        //ERROR
                        $outputTblEvolucion .= " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?currentPage=$x"
                                                                                ."&searchByRut=$searchByRut"
                                                                                ."&dv=$dv
                                                                                    '>$x</a> ";

                    }
                }
            }

            // if not on last page, show forward and last page links        
            if ($currentPage != $totalPages)
            {
                // get next page
                $nextpage = $currentPage + 1;
                // echo forward link for next page
                //Here is wich I think I am doing something wrong and I though to pass also my variable searchByRut but I am not able to received after pressing click on "Next Page"
                $outputTblEvolucion .= " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?currentPage=$nextpage"
                                                                          ."&searchByRut=$searchByRut"
                                                                          ."&dv=$dv
                                                                            '>Next Page</a> ";
                // echo forward link for lastpage
                $outputTblEvolucion .= " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?currentPage=$totalPages"
                                                                          ."&searchByRut=$searchByRut"
                                                                          ."&dv=$dv
                                                                            '>Last Page</a> ";
            } // end if
        }
    }
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Pagination with Form</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Pagination with Form</h1>
        <form id="frmPacienteBuscar" action="" method="get">
            <fieldset>
                <span class="error"><?= $searchByRut_error ?></span><br>
                RUT: <input name="searchByRut" id="searchByRut" type="text" placeholder="Search by RUT.." tabindex="2" size="15" maxlength="8"
                            value="<?= $searchByRut ?>" > - 
                     <input name="dv" id="dv" type="text" value="<?= $dv_input ?>" size="1" tabindex="2" maxlength="1"
                            value="<?= $dv_input ?>" >  Sample: 12345678-1<br>
                <button name="buscar" type="submit" id="contact-submit" data-submit="...Sending">Search</button><br>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
        <?php
            /*Here I will be printing the result of:
                - the main table from tblPaciente
                - the table which I required to do pagination tblEvolucion
                - the links to navigate to the next and previous pages
            */
            echo $outputTblPaciente;
            echo "<br>";
            echo $outputData;
            echo "<br>";
            echo $outputTblEvolucion;
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```